# How to upload arbitrary number of files with different file types

Tags: python, selenium, file-upload, xpath

I am using Selenium and Python to try to automate testing of `CVs` that are uploaded to the server. I figured out everything except how to upload a folder of files one by one(around 11 files) with different file types like `.odt, .doc, .docx, .pdf, .eml` files. I planned to rename files to something like `001.doc, 002.pdf` and so on and use loop to upload them one by one by iterating in `for x in range(1, x)` and appending `x` to the `PATH_TO_FILE = "Path\00" + x` which would give `"Path\001.file_type"`. So the main issue is: can I somehow upload folder one by one without renaming them? Those are CVs and they have random names. And also, how to deal with the problem of file types because they are all different. I found that the only way is to send_keys to the input type file to upload a doc and that requires absolute path to the file.

The testing suite I am trying to build is very rough one at the moment and I managed to deal with finding elements using XPATH only but this problem of uploading left me stumped.

```
# Find browse button
    browse_button = self.retrieve_browse_button
    # Type in path to CVs
    PATH_TO_CVS = "C:\\11MainTestCVS\\00"
    for x in range(1, 12):
      browse_button.send_keys(PATH_TO_CVS + x + file_type) # How to determine file type?
    # Click load
    xpath = "//a[contains(@href, 'javascript:submitCV()')]"
    self.webdriver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I got your question you are searching for glob:

```
from os import path
from glob import glob
EXTENSIONS = ['*.pdf', '*.eml', '*.doc']
DOC_PATH = '/PATH/TO/YOUR/FILES'

files = []    
for ext in EXTENSIONS:
    files.extend(glob(path.join(DOC_PATH, ext)))

# files will now contain all files in DOCPATH with EXTENSIONS
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. It definitely helped. I now have a bundle of absolute paths to correct files with correct extensions and can now send them for upload via send_keys method safely. I will check out and read more on glob.